# Mac mouse cursor-pointer SIZE does NOT change when shaking

Tags: mac, mouse

Mac mouse cursor-pointer SIZE does NOT change when shaking, even when "Apple - System Preferences - Accessibility - Display - Shake mouse pointer to locate" is selected.

System: macOS 10.12.6 (16G2136) Sierra.

How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the size of cursor in System Preferences/Accessibility/Display?  Be sure to set cursor size at least halfway up the scale.

Comment: It should work with the cursor size set to Normal, hard left. Mine does. Are you shaking for long enough? It takes about 5 or 6 left/right moves in rapid succession to fully expand & if you're not fast enough it never expands. It also hast to be left/right or in circles. Up/down doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. None of that works. It used to work before, but some time ago it stopped working. I guess there is something interfering with it, but I wonder what is it.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was the Wacom One driver!!!

Comment: Fixed with macOS 11.3 (20E232) Big Sur and maybe older versions as well.